# Meteor Heavy Helper Design Pattern

Tags: meteor

So, meteor reruns helper code every time it is called in the template, right? My issue is that I have a heavy helper that returns a large object. I'm iterating over a list of these objects and then over some nested objects which is resulting in a really big lag.

So, are there any design patterns that prevent recalling the whole helper every time? Or do I just need to break up my object?

```
Template.deliveries.helpers({
    current_delivery: function() {
        var delivery_id = Template.instance().data.current_delivery_id;
        var delivery    = Deliveries.findOne({'_id': delivery_id});
        var project     = Projects.findOne({'_id':Session.get('current_project_id')});

        var secondary_profile_names = [];
        if (Session.get('delivery_include_secondaries')) {
            for (var n in project.delivery_profiles) {
                if (project.delivery_profiles[n].name === delivery.delivery_profile) {
                    if (project.delivery_profiles[n].secondary_deliverables) {
                        secondary_profile_names = project.delivery_profiles[n].secondary_deliverables;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $("#delivery-profile").val(delivery.delivery_profile);

        var elements = $.map(delivery.elements, function(id, idx) {
            i_el = InternalElements.findOne({'_id': id});
            i_el.source_element = SourceElements.findOne({'_id':i_el.source_element});

            if (secondary_profile_names) {
                i_el.secondary_elements = InternalElements.find({
                    'source_element':i_el.source_element._id,
                    'name':{'$in': secondary_profile_names},
                    "$or": [{'is_primary':false}, {'is_primary': {'$exists':false}}]
                },{
                    'sort':{'version':-1},
                    'limit':1
                }).fetch();
            } else {
                i_el.secondary_elements = [];
            }

            return i_el;
        });
        delivery.elements = elements.sort(function(a,b) { return (a.shot_name > b.shot_name) - (a.shot_name < b.shot_name); });

        return delivery;
    },
});
```

Comment: it's really complex break up everything and organize everything it's too much stuff in just one helper think about on how you can do it differently

Comment: If you want to only call it once, you can preserve the context using `#with`.

Comment: I'm not finding this to be true. Seems every time I reference any helper, even within a `with` statement, the helper reprocesses. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I've used successfully is to cache the results of expensive computations in a *local collection*.

```
MyLocalCache = new Mongo.Collection();
```

I like to make objects in this collection 1:1 with the original object so I reuse the `_id` from the original along with any keys and values that don't require transformation then extend the object with the transformed values.